# Finding the right Gradle plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle-plugin

How do I find the gradle plugin and gradle version that supports both the features in experimental plugin 0.2.0 ( for NDK support as per [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) ) and beta plugin 1.4.0 beta 3 ( for vector assets support as per [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/android-studio-14.html)